Why does a second window open when a test fails in VSCode?
I'm facing an issue in Visual Studio Code (VSCode). When I run my tests and one of them fails, a second window opens unexpectedly. The terminal already displays the test output, so I don't understand why this second window is being opened.
I expect to see only the terminal output with the test results, but instead, I also get a second VSCode window popping up, which is unnecessary and distracting.
How can I turn it off?
Here below example what I mean, I expected only termnial output


For clarity: is it a new window or is your current window split. If it's a split is it in your screenshot horizontal or vertical, i.e. the test results on the right?
